# I'm not sure why but my add force isn't working i have a rigidbody2d, and the code looks correct but it still won't work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not sure why but my .addforce on my rigidbody isn't working.

I have tried following the official unity addforce tutorial.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public Vector2 pos;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        faceMouse();
        testForClick();
    }

    void faceMouse()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 differance = GameObject.Find("gunArm").transform.position - mousePos;
        float gunAngle = Mathf.Atan2(differance.y, differance.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        GameObject.Find("gunArm").transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, gunAngle);
    }

    void testForClick()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            print("click");
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect arrow to have force added to it in the forwards direction but it just prints out "click" (The message I added to ensure the mouse-click was working).

Comment: you should use it in `FixedUpdate`

Comment: I just tried this and it has made no difference, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but I created a test script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 20.0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            print("click");

            rb.AddForce(transform.right * speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        rotate();
    }

    private void rotate()
    {

    }
}
```

I also edited my old script to this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 50.0f;
    public Vector2 pos;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        faceMouse();
        testForClick();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (doForce == true)
        {
            doForce = false;
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private bool doForce;

    private GameObject gunArm;
    private Camera cam;

    private void faceMouse()
    {
        // try to reuse the reference
        if (!cam) cam = Camera.main;

        var mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // try to re-use the reference
        if (!gunArm) gunArm = GameObject.Find("gunArm");

        var difference = rb.transform.position - mousePos;
        var gunAngle = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, gunAngle);
    }

    void testForClick()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            print("click");

            // only set the flag
            doForce = true;
        }
    }

    void place()
    {

    }
}
```

and the test worked by itself with no rotation and on the main script only the rotation worked so i tried having both scripts active at the same time and it started working, thanks for all the help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that `isn't working` is a quite weak description:

First of all you should do it in `FixedUpdate` but get the input in `Update`.

Second reduce the `Find` calls in `Update` .. very inefficient. It would be better to reference them via the Inspector if possible. Otherwise maybe in `Start` .. the way I show here is the last resort with lazy initialization assuming your script might be spawned later on runtime

Additionally (thanks to EricOverflow) you might want to rather pass [`ForceMode.Impulse`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.Impulse.html) to `AddForce` since you add the force only once and not continuesly.

```
public class ArrowController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    public Vector2 pos;

    // store and re-use references!
    // would be better to already reference them via drag&drop
    // in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private GameObject gunArm;
    [SerializeField] private Camera cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        testForClick();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // also do this here
        faceMouse();

        if (doForce)
        {
            doForce = false;
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private bool doForce;



    private void faceMouse()
    {
        // try to reuse the reference
        if(!cam) cam = Camera.main;

        var mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        // try to re-use the reference
        if (!gunArm) gunArm = GameObject.Find("gunArm");

        var difference = gunArm.transform.position - mousePos;
        var gunAngle = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        gunArm.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, gunAngle);
    }

    private void testForClick()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            print("click");

            // only set the flag
            doForce = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to cross-sync input and physics between the Update/FixedUpdate cycles can get very tricky, and it is likely overkill in this scenario. Simply changing the ForceMode to impulse in the AddForce call would remove the risk involved with leaving the logic in Update.

Comment: @ErikOverflow not that tricky .. there is a simple flag that gets set and reset ;)

Comment: I have done this code in my script but i am still not seeing any movement when I click.

Comment: well maybe the force is too weak? did you try something like e.g. `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 20f, ForceMode.Impulse);` depending on your objects weight

Comment: Adding a flag to communicate between Update/FixedUpdate is effectively doing the same thing as "GetMouseButtonDown" which sets a flag for 1 Update(). The AddForce is queued until the next physics cycle automatically. If physics were being applied continuously then I would absolutely recommend splitting responsibility between the 2 methods, but since it's an impulse action it is overcomplicating this problem.

Comment: @ErikOverflow it doesn't matter ... Unity allways uses it in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) and I would stick to it .. just to be sure

Comment: There's no ambiguity, though, so there's no need to do extra work just to be sure. Unity queues physics changes between cycles and automatically handles this impulse-based force. Continuous forces need to be handled more actively, but not this one.

Comment: I just threw together a quick test script which is the same as my code but without the rotation and it works so the problem must be with the rotation part.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't do anything is not because it doesn't work, but instead because transform.forward is a vector with magnitude 1. Adding a force of magnitude 1 will not do much to most objects, and friction will likely slow down the object again.

Try adding a force with a higher strength and ForceMode.Impulse instead:

```
float strength = 50f;
rb.AddForce(transform.forward * strength, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

### Update:

It looks like you want the gun to face your mouse position and that's where your problem might be:
Let's try using Quaternion.LookRotation to get that working instead of doing to math manually.

Maybe:

```
GameObject gunArm;

void Awake()
{
    gunArm = GameObject.Find("gunArm");
}

void faceMouse()
{
    Vector3 difference = mousePos - gunArm.transform.position;
    difference.z = 0;
    gunArm.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(difference);
}
```

Comment: I just threw together a quick test script which is the same as my code but without the rotation and it works so the problem must be with the rotation part.

Comment: Ahh, you want the gun to face the mouse, but I think I see some issues. let me write a new answer.

Comment: @theglozzom Give my update a shot and let me know if that works better. I moved your GameObject.Find to the Awake method since it only needs to run once. GameObject.Find is expensive, so you should consider serializing the reference via inspector as DerHugo suggested elsewhere.